# Visual Studio 2008 adding incorrect working folders to TFS Workspace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 with TFS. I have one workspace set up with one working folder.  I map the root source control folder $/ to C:\TFS and get all code.  When working on any project under the root, Visual Studio will randomly add incorrectly mapped working folders to my workspace.

For example, it might map $/WebProject/ to C:\TFS\WebProject\DataAccess -- where the real files exist at C:\TFS\WebProject.

Once it incorrectly adds these working folders, I can no longer open the solution.  I am forced to remove the working folders that Visual Studio added and get latest from TFS.

Has anyone experienced this?  Is there something I can do to avoid running into this?

Answer (score 3):

go to "Source Control Explorer". Click on the "Workspace" dropdown. Select "Workspaces" and delete any custom workspaces you don't need.

Update:

Your vs2008 TFS cache might be corrupt. Your cache is located here:

C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\1.0\Cache

Install Team Foundation Sidekick and look at your workspaces

http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

http://www.attrice.info/images/workspace_sk_screen.gif

What do you see there?

Comment: I only have one workspace and one working folder defined.  The issue is that Visual Studio is adding working folders that are incorrectly mapped to my existing workspace.

Comment: The workspace loads.  It also shows the extra incorrect mappings.  I think this may happen after one team member checks in code, and I get latest.  Does that make any sense?

Comment: Did you install Sidekick? Can you upload a photo of what you see in Sidekick (afer, obviously, redacting sensitive information)